# Laravel 5.8 - Eloquent not listening to where on relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to do a where query on my relation called `employee_label`.

The table `employee_label` looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+----------+
| id | employee_id | label_id |
+----+-------------+----------+
|  1 |         123 |      123 |
|  2 |         456 |      456 |
|  3 |         768 |      768 |
+----+-------------+----------+
```

The other `where()` and `orWhere()` get passed an empty `array()` by default, but could contain data as for example: `['inactive' => 0]`.

**Expected result:** 
I expect to only receive the employees with for example label `123` when I provide label `123` as `where()` for the relation.

**Actual result:** 
All employees are returned, the data is not filtered.

**Code:**

```
$employees = Employee::with(['employee_label' => function($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('label_id', '=', $request->get('label'));
}])->where($searchQuery)->orWhere($orQuery)->orderBy('inactive', 'asc')->paginate(20);
```

**What I've tried:**
I've tried to change the `$query->where('label_id')` to `$query->where('employee_label.label_id')` with no change in the result.

**Model `Employee`**

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'employees';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'surname',
        'inactive',
        'entered_into_service'
    ];

    public function employee_label() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\EmployeeLabel');
    }

}
```

**Model `EmployeeLabel`**

```
class EmployeeLabel extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'employee_label';
    protected $fillable = [
        'employee_id',
        'label_id'
    ];

    public function employee() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
    }

    public function label() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Label');
    }

}
```

Comment: I think, You have `->orWhere($orQuery)` making the conditionals before it optional, so you may need to put it inside the closure.

Comment: Please also post your models too

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Just tried removing the `->orWhere()`, unfortunately with the same result.

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz Added them to the post.

Comment: @ChrisDekker can you please log the sql query you are generating and post it here?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Managed to solve it using the solution I just posted.

Comment: @ChrisDekker good 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search I've finally found the answer to this weird problem.

Apparently instead of using `Employee::with()` you have to use `Employee::whereHas()`.

So the final code will be:

```
$employees = Employee::whereHas('employee_label', function($query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('label_id', '=', $request->get('label'));
})->where($searchQuery)->orWhere($orQuery)->orderBy('inactive', 'asc')->paginate(20);
```

See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) for more information.

Thanks all who helped!

Comment: Yes you are correct, to filter models based on related models, you need to use `whereHas` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the employee model to:

```
    public function employeeLabel() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\EmployeeLabel', 'employee_id', 'id');
    }
```

That binds the relationship automatically so you do not need to in the eloquent call.

Then the method to get all employees and associated labels and return paginated with:

```
$employees = Employee::all()->with('employeeLabel')
                            ->orderBy('inactive', 'asc')
                            ->paginate(20);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot to return your **$query** object

Instead of

```
$query->where('label_id', '=', $request->get('label'));
```

Try returning your $query from a **employee_label** callback method

```
return $query->where('label_id', '=', $request->get('label'));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the `return` didn't change the result.

Comment: this is wrong answer, he clearly mentioned that he want to filter models based on related models.